# Lens focusing a collimated beam into a disk of some material. Focus shift due to movement of material?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, photonics

I encountered a geometric optics problem that gave the example of a lens focusing a collimated beam into a disk of some material with refractive index $n$. It then claimed that, if the disk moves towards the lens a distance $t$, whilst ensuring that the focus still remains inside the material, then the focus shifts by $nt$ inside the material. This assumes the paraxial approximation.

However, no explanation is provided as to *why* the focus shifts by $nt$, nor is any explanation provided as to *how* one comes to this result.

I have previously derived the following equation for the **transverse shift** of a ray when travelling through air and hitting a slab of some material:

$$x = d \sin(\theta) \left[ 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(\theta)}}{\sqrt{n^2 - \sin^2(\theta)}} \right],$$

where $d$ is the thickness of the material. I then used this to find subsequent **focus shift** along the optical axis:

$$F_2 - F_1 = \dfrac{x}{\sin(\theta)}$$

It seems to me that these are the relevant results in deriving the focus shift for a problem such as this. However, I've so far been unable to use them to derive $nt$.

My immediate thought was that I could use $F_2 - F_1 = \dfrac{x}{\sin(\theta)}$ to solve this problem, but, even after making the paraxial approximation, it doesn't seem to get me the desired result (unless I've made an error):

$$\begin{align} F_2 - F_1 &= \dfrac{x}{\theta} \\ &= \dfrac{d \theta \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)}{\theta} \\ &= d \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{n} \right) \end{align}$$

And this doesn't seem to account for $t$, the shift of the material towards to lens.

My sketch of the problem is as follows:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law

Comment: @S.McGrew If I derived the transverse shift $x = d \sin(\theta) \left[ 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(\theta)}}{\sqrt{n^2 - \sin^2(\theta)}} \right]$, then I don't think not knowing Snell's law is the problem...

Comment: A straightforward way to estimate the location of the focus is to use Snell's law to trace the two most extreme-angle rays and see how their crossing point changes as the surface of the medium is shifted.

Comment: Isnt the paraxial approximation that sin theta= tan theta= theta?

Comment: @lalala That is correct.

Comment: @S.McGrew But how is this different from the derivation of the transverse shift? In particular, I'm unsure of how we incorporate the shift of the material towards the lens by $t$.

Comment: It's just using Snells law and some simple geometry. The beam travels in 2 phases, the first is before it hits the spherical surface. In this phase the beam has angle $\theta_1$. Calculate the y-distance covered in this phase for a lense-spherical surface-distance of $D$. Now calculate the x-distance covered in the second phase. In this phase the beam has angle $\theta_2$. Just calculate $\theta_2=\theta_2(D)$ by using snells law. Calculate how much x-distance $d=d(D)$ the beam covers before it hits $y=0$. Now you get a Function $D_{total}(D)=D+d(D)$. Calculate $D_{total}(D)-D_{total}(D+t)$.

Comment: How about you do these calculations and post them as an addition to your question and we help you out once you get stuck?

Comment: @ThePointer, your drawing looks like the light enters the edge of the disk (rather than the flat face of the disk), but your words don't say that.  It does make a difference because the edge of a disk would act as a lens.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**First attack**: The answer seems independent of disc and lens geometry.

Consider the following fig1: 
[image: ray diagram: a ray approaches a vertical half-plane of index eta]

Here instead of a disc we use a vertical half-plane of index $\eta$. $d$ is where the ray would have focused if there wasn't any material. In the presence of material the ray focuses at $d'$

Clearly,

$$d'=d\frac{tan(i)}{tan(r)}\approx d\eta$$
using small-angle approximation.Therefore
$$\Delta d'=\Delta d \eta$$
for displacements along the optical axis. If the material is displaced by $t$ towards the lens i.e. $\Delta d=t$, then focus shifts by $\Delta d'=\eta t$

As long as small-angle approx. holds, observe that
 1. the result is same even if the material wasn't vertical. This is since all the tilt would do is change $i$.
 2. a disc at each point of incidence is just a tilted tangent plane

---

**Second attack**: lens equation

For a spherical lens of

1. radius $R$
2. refractive index $\eta$
3. object distance $u$
4. image distance $v$
5. foal length $f$

The following holds :

$$-\frac{1}{u}+\frac{\eta}{v}=\frac{1}{f}=\frac{\eta-1}{R}$$

under

1. small angle approx &
2. cartesian convention &
3. the lens extends indefinitely on the right

Rearranging
$$v=\frac{\eta f u}{f+u}$$

therfore for $u'=u-t$,
$$v'-v=\frac{\eta t}{(1+\frac{u}{f})(1+\frac{u-t}{f})}$$

In the regime $t\ll u\ll f$, to first order $\Delta v=v'-v=\eta t$

Comment: Can you please show how you got $d'=d\frac{tan(i)}{tan(r)}$? The trigonometry used here is not clear to me.

Comment: @ThePointer $\tan i=\frac hd$, $\tan r=\frac {h}{d'}$, where $h$ is the height of the point of refraction from the principal axis